# Getting minimum date from a list of records with date columns

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that returns a list of rows from DB:

```
var records = (from t in this.Context.MyTable where SomeConditionsAreTrue select t).ToList();
```

one of the column this table has is `OriginalAppDate` which is a `nullable DateTime` column.

I want to **find the earliest date populated in that OriginalAppDate where it IS NOT NULL**

What I have written is this, my database isn't ready and some code issues so I can't run it to test so wanted to take a look and get feedback if this sounds right?

```
var tempDateTime = records.Where(t => t.OriginalAppDate.HasValue).Min(t => t.OriginalAppDate.Value);
```

also when I say this below compiler says this expression is always false? **so how would I know if it returned a value or not?**

```
if(tempDateTime == null)
{
    //... 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select entire row then you can just order by date and select the first row. You are guaranteed to pick of nonnullable rows since you are filtering those ones:

```
var minRecord = records.Where(t => t.OriginalAppDate.HasValue).
                        OrderBy(t => t.OriginalAppDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: lol yeah! hadn't thought about that. Ok one question : How to also make sure date is NOT NULL ?

Comment: You are guaranteed to pick out of nonnullable rows since you are filtering those ones

Comment: oh I see, because of the HasValue you have there, and if it returns nothing I can jsut check for minRecord==null